# Will window.addEventListener be removed on close?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

My app has an external `Iframe` in it and an `eventListener` is added to the `Iframe`'s `window` object.
In this case, is a `removeEventListener` required or will the listener be removed on `Iframe` close?

Comment: You quistion is not clear. what kind of EventListener? You add Event Listener in your code, so whenever your website calls for the code, it runs and listens to your window. But if you close your window, it means you close your website and there is no code to listen to your window.

Comment: If by window you mean browser tab (or whole browser) - of course, all code and it's instance will be removed from process. So basically when you close your tab/browser - all JS executions on this tab/browser stops.

Answer (score 1):

When you **close** the `window`, The entire page will be closed. So when you **re-open**, It **won't** be opening from the previous state.

So when you close the window, The current page **including `browser session, events & listeners, http requests & etc`** will be terminated.